# rgbd_launch does publish image_rec

Tags: ros-hydro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In Hydro, I create a launch file with the following to get data from my attached Kinect:

It publishes a lot of stuff but not "/camera/depth_registered/image_rect". This worked fine with Groovy.

Dave

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/139631/rgbd_launch-does-publish-image_rec/) by [davevh](https://answers.ros.org/users/4119/davevh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 36 on 2014-03-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Misleading title: should be openni_launch does not publish image_rect.

In Hydro, I create a launch file with the following to get data from my attached Kinect:

```
<include file="$(find openni_launch)/launch/openni.launch" />"
<node pkg="dynamic_reconfigure" type="dynparam" name="dynparam" args="set_from_parameters /camera/driver">
  <param name="image_mode" value="2" />
  <param name="depth_mode" value="2" /> 
  <param name="depth_registration" value="true" />
  <param name="data_skip" value="5" />
</node>
```

It publishes a lot of stuff but not "/camera/depth_registered/image_rect". This worked fine with Groovy.

Dave

---

Originally posted by [davevh](https://answers.ros.org/users/4119/davevh/) with karma: 36 on 2014-03-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0